# Android - RemoveUpdates not removing listener

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been trying to remove location updates from my location manager however the GPS symbol continuously shows even after removeupdates has been called. I've ensured the correct listener variable name has been passed and the code is executed for the listener update. I only want to find the user's location once.

Thanks

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnCameraChangeListener {

    Map<Marker, Integer> markers = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
    VenueManager venueManager;
    GoogleMap map;
    long last_map_refresh = 0;
    Button search_btn;
    CameraPosition previous_position = null;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final long MIN_TIME = 400;
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private Button add_venue;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private LatLng user_position = null;
    private NetworkManager network_manager;
    private Boolean first_map_render = false;
    private LocationListener location_listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("GPS not enabled");  // GPS not found
            builder.setMessage("This application requires you to enable GPS location settings. We recommend that you enable 'Use wireless networks' and 'Use GPS satellites'. Would you like to enable this setting now?"); // Want to enable?
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                    MapActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent home_intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home_intent);
                    Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "You will not be able to use the map features of this application until you enable gps settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });

            builder.create().show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            network_manager = new NetworkManager();

            location_listener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
                    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    draw_map(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).build());
                    user_position = latLng;

                    locationManager.removeUpdates(location_listener);
             };

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, location_listener);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all when using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` you should not see the GPS symbol at all.

I see you are using Google Maps Android API v2, so my guess is outside of the code you put here you have

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

which shows blue dot and continuously updates it while showing `Activity` with `MapFragment`/`MapView`.

Comment: Yes that's correct I've got that set outside of this code. Would this contribute to the GPS symbol coming up?

Comment: @Garbit Yes. `GoogleMap` uses `LoactionClient` which uses `LocationManager` with both GPS and NETWORK providers internally.

Comment: Does it drain the battery and should I be setting it to false after a short period?

Comment: First of all `LocationClient` uses less battery than `LocationManager` with GPS. It is said to be using 1% of battery per hour. It is also active only when your `Activity` is showing (between `onResume` and `onPause`). It all depends on the requirements, but usually people don't have map open for a long time. The display would take more battery anyway.